# open Module Doesn't Work for Full Browser Path

Tags: node.js

```
const open = require('open')

const main = async () => {
    await open('https://google.com', {
        app: {
            name: 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
        }
    });
}
main();
```

Why this code doesn't work on W10? Passing full path browser .exe as an argument works only under Linux? Is that why the creator mentions WSL specifically?

> You may also pass in the app's full path. For example on WSL, this can
> be /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe for
> the Windows installation of Chrome.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/open

Comment: As a guess - the spaces in the path might be a problem. Try surrounding the whole path in quotes.

Comment: What do you mean by quotes? I used the ' character, which should be sufficient.

Comment: `'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'` -> `'"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"'`

Comment: It makes no difference. Does it work for you?

Comment: I currently cannot test it. As I said, it's a guess - sometimes paths with spaces are a problem, so the path has to be surrounded by quotes. If it's not that, I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: I think the problem is the syntax, as the author of the open module provides no syntax example on how to use the full path option.